# Oracle Connection request timed out (in BizTalk after Oracle is recycled)

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2016

Normally everything is working fine, but every time Oracle is recycled for maintenance or patches, we get this error, coming from a BizTalk 2016 SendPort:

> Error Description:
> Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.ConnectionException:
> Connection request timed out --->
> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:   Connection request timed
> out

Our current "get around" is to recycle the BizTalk Host Instance, but as this can occur on off hours and weekends, that is not an ideal situation, better to somehow avoid the error altogether.

The SendPort has this property: UseOracleConnectionPool = True,
which according to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-oracle-database/read-about-the-oracle-database-adapter-binding-properties):

> ODP.NET property. Specifies whether to use the ODP.NET connection
> pool. The default is True, which enables connection pooling. The
> Oracle Database adapter implements connection pooling by using the
> ODP.NET connection pool.

So I would like to know if setting this parm to False might avoid this error (at the cost of slower connections).  Of course we can test it, but it takes a team of a few people to set it up, recycle Oracle, and try it again. (I'm not yet sure which release of Oracle it is.)

Comment: Usually there are parameter to test/reset/recycle connections automatically at the connection level?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue, restarting the Host Instance is our workaround as well.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - do script or schedule the restarts? We could have a process where the Oracle DBA has to run a script, but then we need to give him BTAdmin, or create a web service or something to do it.

Comment: Currently manual restarts when we notice the issue.

Comment: Did you get around to doing that testing to see if that UseOracleConnectionPool had any impact?

Comment: No, too many people involved in the test.  We are about to test everything in 2020 now, so maybe then.